# import equivalent for require in app.use()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require, es6-modules

I have the following code in my server.js file:

```
import express from "express";
import fs from "fs";
const app = express();

fs.readdirSync("./routes").map((r) =>
  app.use("/api", require(`./routes/${r}`)));

app.listen(8000, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

I need to use type: "module" in my package.json and was able to convert most of my code from require to import, but I can't figure out how to do this when the require is the callback function. I tried using an asynchronous call to import(), but that left the server hanging, so I don't think that's the way to go. For reference, this is what I tried:

```
fs.readdirSync("./routes").map((r) =>
  app.use("/api", async () => {
    await import(`./routes/${r}`);
  })
);
```

and this is one of the files in my routes folder:

```
import express from "express";
import { register, login } from "../controllers/auth.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", register);
router.post("/login", login);
export default router;
```

I don't know where to go from here, there's not much documentation on this, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use top level `await` in modules.

```js
for (const r of fs.readdirSync("./routes")) {
    app.use("/api", (await import(`./routes/${r}`)).default);
}
```